# How do you make a Firefox extension password protected?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, installation

As in, when I install an add-on, and Firefox restarts, it should accept a password (only the first time when installing). And when the user wants to disable or remove the add-on, it will only comply upon entering the same password? In which part would the code be kept?

Comment: I do not believe Firefox extensions can reject an attempt to disable or uninstall themselves.  What is the purpose of this extension?

Comment: It's supposed to be history monitor...therfore, even if the user realizes this and tries to remove it,it shouldn't allow it without the password...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Even if you disable add-on uninstall - the user can always close the browser and remove the extension manually (removing the directory on disk will do).

That said, the secure way of storing passwords is the [login manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsILoginManager). They will be stored encrypted on disk if the user defines a master password. Of course, the user himself can always see the stored passwords (under Options / Security / Saved Passwords). So you probably want to store a salted [hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICryptoHash) of the password rather than the password itself.

You can also use [AddonManager.addAddonListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#addAddonListener%28%29) to get notified whenever an add-on is being disabled or uninstalled. You can cancel the action by calling [addon.cancelUninstall()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/Addon#cancelUninstall%28%29) or setting `addon.userDisabled = false`.

The above is merely for reference - it won't really help you achieve your goal.